# Xtrabackup "Error: failed to execute query SET SESSION lock_wait_timeout=31536000: Lost connection to MySQL server during query"

Tags: mysql, percona-xtradb-cluster

There is the backup log, but the backup works well at yesterday, what is wrong?

Mysql is：5.6.28

xtrabackup is：2.4.6

```
Unrecognized character \x01; marked by <-- HERE after <-- HERE near column 1 at - line 1374.
171107 01:36:18 Connecting to MySQL server host: 172.0.0.40, user: root, password: set, port: 3306, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
Using server version 5.6.28-76.1-56-log
xtrabackup version 2.4.6 based on MySQL server 5.7.13 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 8ec05b7)
xtrabackup: uses posix_fadvise().
xtrabackup: cd to /var/lib/mysql
xtrabackup: open files limit requested 0, set to 1048576
xtrabackup: using the following InnoDB configuration:
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_home_dir = .
xtrabackup:   innodb_data_file_path = ibdata1:12M:autoextend
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_group_home_dir = ./
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_files_in_group = 2
xtrabackup:   innodb_log_file_size = 134217728
InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
171107 01:36:18 >> log scanned up to (12857047584)
xtrabackup: Generating a list of tablespaces
InnoDB: Allocated tablespace ID 2723 for management/HzsInsertUserInfoTemp, old maximum was 0
171107 01:36:19 [01] Copying ./ibdata1 to /xtrabackup_backupfiles/ibdata1
171107 01:36:19 >> log scanned up to (12857047584)
171107 01:36:20 [01]        ...done

......
......
......

171107 01:37:40 >> log scanned up to (12857139552)
Error: failed to execute query SET SESSION lock_wait_timeout=31536000: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Comment: I've had this kind of problem if I had a `pt-kill` running that killed idle connections. When XtraBackup starts, it opens a connection, and then uses that connection at the end, after all the data has been copied. If you kill that connection by accident, this kind of failure happens.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql> show variables like '%timeout%';
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 300      |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout    | 300      |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
+-----------------------------+----------+`

`mysql> show  global  variables like  '%timeout%';
+-----------------------------+----------+
| Variable_name               | Value    |
+-----------------------------+----------+
| connect_timeout             | 10       |
| delayed_insert_timeout      | 300      |
| have_statement_timeout      | YES      |
| innodb_flush_log_at_timeout | 1        |
| innodb_lock_wait_timeout    | 50       |
| innodb_rollback_on_timeout  | OFF      |
| interactive_timeout         | 28800    |
| lock_wait_timeout           | 31536000 |
| net_read_timeout            | 30       |
| net_write_timeout           | 300      |
| rpl_stop_slave_timeout      | 31536000 |
| slave_net_timeout           | 3600     |
| thread_pool_idle_timeout    | 300      |
| wait_timeout                | 28800    |
+-----------------------------+----------+`